# Service for accessing multiple user cloud storage accounts from single server

Tags: google-drive-api, cloud, storage, dropbox, onedrive

I'm working on a free educational web app for school music teachers and students that will allow them to collaborate and share mp3 recordings. Since earning revenue is not the goal, I'm looking for ways to reduce file storage costs. A single teacher assignment might produce hundreds of recorded responses. Instead of saving these recordings to my own storage (or to a service like Amazon's S3), I was wondering if there are any cloud storage services that teachers could sign up for - similar to something like Google Drive - and which they could then give my server app access to for storing their class's recordings. I'd still manage the info for the recordings and other data in a single database on my own server, but I'd save any large files to the shared storage provided to me by each teacher. I haven't found any examples of this sort of thing with services like Google Drive or Dropbox, but if it's possible with those or any other services, I'd appreciate a link to some info. The expectation would be that a teacher could pay the storage company for its service according to the school's usage. The service would have to be simple for teachers to sign up for and provide me access to, which I think puts some of the developer-oriented services out of reach.

Suggestions for different strategies are also welcome. I'd prefer not to handle financial transactions (so I don't want to rent space to people).

Comment: I'm sure this is possible with Google Drive, Dropbox, and OneDrive (and probably a number of other services). What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I've mostly just been reading through the API documentations to see if I can figure out whether it's possible. With Google Drive, I see how I can set up a service account that will allow the server to essentially act as a user (or on behalf of users), but I don't see how it can be set up to access a shared folder on another user's Google Drive account. It may be possible, but so far I'm not putting the pieces together from the examples of other use cases. I'll keep studying it. Thanks for responding.